# Parse Custom cell show image according to boolean

Tags: ios, parsing, boolean, parse-platform

I want to set ImageView hidden or not according to the boolean value true x false, which is located in Parse database. Could you give me some ideas how to do that? Got problems because of having property ImageView in my CustomCell.h

EDIT:

```
PFObject *yes = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
    cell.discounts.hidden = [yes[@"yesnocolumn"] boolValue];
```

I just don`t understand to usage of PFObject, myclass returning (null) value.

EDIT2:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Classname"];
    [query whereKey:@"yesnocolumn" equalTo:@1];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            cell.discounts.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            cell.discounts.hidden = NO;

        }}];
```

Comment: So yes should be non-nil, but yes[@"yesnocolumn"] will be nil (uninitialized) so boolValue will be 0 and hidden will be NO. So the discounts subview of cell will be visible.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, that`s it. And if the boolValue will be YES, image won`t be visible.

Comment: But the yesnocolumn is uninitialized, so it will be false. Do you see that?

Comment: I do, so now I have to subclass PFObject as a part of PFQuery or how do I initialize PFObject?

Answer (score 2):

The boolean from the service will look like either @0 or @1, so you can't just test for truthiness, because:

```
if (@0) {
    // this condition is true.  that's surprising!
}
```

So the safe way to test is to say:

```
cell.imageView.hidden = [myParseObject[@"hidden"] boolValue];
```

EDIT - Now I understand the misunderstanding.  Here's how parse works:

1) Create an object locally:

```
PFObject *yes = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
```

This object won't have any values initialized.  So any bools it contains will be 0, or NO.

2) Set some value locally:

```
yes[@"yesnocolumn"] = @1;  // makes it true
// or = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

3) Save it.  (you can also use the data browser to initialize objects manually).

```
[yes saveInBackground];
```

4) Get an object.   I think this is the part that's giving you trouble... just creating a local object doesn't really do much.  The idea of parse is that objects are stored in the cloud.  To get them, you need a PFQuery.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // this will return all (up to 100 by default, MyClass objects that are
    // saved in the cloud
    if (!error && results.count) {
        NSLog(@"the first object is %@", results[0]);
        NSLog(@"the bool is %d", [results[0][@"yesnocolumn"] boolValue];
    }
}];
```

Does this make sense?  You can't expect the object to have any values initialized until you either set them locally, or retrieve already initialized remote copies.  Also note, if you run the query on the next source line after saveInBackground, you won't get the saved result, since the save won't have finished.  Start out saving in one run of your app, then reviewing in the data browser, then do a query.

It's worth doing a thorough review of [their docs here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS).

Comment: I did it in the way you said but have none effect .             PFObject *yes = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Praseclassname"];
cell.image.hidden = [yes[@"classcolumn"] boolValue]; Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code that does the fetch and code that looks inside the object?  Also, I'm interested in what NSLog(@"class is %@", theObject[@"theBoolCol"]); says

Comment: Also, NSLog(@"%@", cell.image);

Comment: @Milan1111 - Please have a look.  The key is to initialize objects either by setting values locally or retrieving ones that have had values set from the cloud using PFQuery.

Comment: Thanks for all but I am still little bit confused. We are talking about objects but I have already my object(ImageView) set inside my app, so I don`t have to get some objects from cloud. I only need to get boolean value. It`s still the same process like you wrote in the answer?

Comment: Pff, I think I wrongly formalized the question. I don`t need to make new row in database. Just read already made boolean column with true/false.

Comment: Ok. Just begin at step 4.

Comment: Danh, could you tell me, what`s the reason, why it is not still working? Please, check my re-edit